# div css top left not working

Tags: html, css

I want to position the top left of a div but its not working...here is the css class for the div

```
.delete-wpr { 
    position: relative; 
}

.delete { 
    display: block; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: -5px; 
}
```

And here is the HTML code:

```
<td class="item-name">
    <div class="delete-wpr">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="items-name[]">Item1</textarea>
        <a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" style="color:#cccccc;"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</td>
```

I want to position span class in middle of the div class "delete-wpr"...but its positioning is not changing even though am changing the top and left value

Can anyone please help me with this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

top and left appear to be working in my jsfiddle with the code you posted: http://jsfiddle.net/28jnp3xs/

```
.delete-wpr { position: relative; }
.delete { 
  display: block; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0px; 
  left: -5px; 
}
```

Maybe you overwrite  `.delete` somewhere in your css?

Comment: ...while changing delete class to delete1 it works...but still that div is not visible in mobile devices

Answer (score 0):

Of course the position is changing. Please try adding some positive value for top and left property. **.delete-wpr** is a block level element which taking entire available space on doc flow.